# Is the centralizer of a Subgroup abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ a subgroup of $G$.
Let: $$c(H)=\{x\in G : xh=hx, \forall h\in H \}$$

I have already proved that this is a subgroup of $G$, but I'm not sure if it's abelian (I've been looking for a counterexample of this but without success so far).

Another question, how can I express the Center of G $Z(G)=\{z\in G : zx=xz, \forall x\in G \}$ in terms of $c(H)$? Is the center abelian?

Thank you for your help, I'm new to groups and I'm kind of lost.

Comment: What is $g$ in the definition of $c(H)$?

Comment: $g$ is a misprint there.

Comment: You're effectively asking "if $a$ commutes with $b$, and $b$ commutes with $c$, then does $a$ commute with $c$"? An unspoken rule of basic group theory is "if you can't prove it easily, then it's false."

Comment: Take a look at my answer here (relevant in particular to $H$ being the trivial subgroup): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/296763/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles I was going  to answer this question until I saw your post, which already had my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A strategy when trying to understand such a notion is to consider *extreme* cases. This is not always helpful, but it cannot hurt and sometimes it is useful.

You have a notion defined for every subgroup. There are two subgroups present for any group $G$, the full group $G$ and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$.

- What is $c(\{e\})$? It is the set of all elements $x \in G$ such that $xe=ex$. But that's of course true for all $x\in G$! So $c(\{e\}) = G$. Thus if  $G$ is not abelian this is not abelian. (For a more concise version of this part see [the post mentioned by Zev](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/296764).)
- What is $c(G)$? It is defined as $\{x\in G : xh=hx, \forall h\in G \}$. But, this looks familiar, doesn't it? it is *exactly* the definition of $Z(G)$ just using different names for the variables.

Thus considering these extreme cases, the two questions almost answered themselves.

Finally on whether $Z(G)$ is abelian.  We need to check if $ab =ba $ for all $a,b \in Z(G)$. But, when $a \in Z(G)$ then by definition it commutes with every element of $G$ thus in particular with $b$. Hence the center is abelian.